# DB tables technical info in SAP Data Dictionary

Tags: sql-server, abap, sap-data-dictionary

I was given a task to develop a report that would present the following details (as separate columns in ALV):
1) Name of the DB table (like MSEG, EKPO etc.)
2) Size of the DB table in megabytes
3) Number of records
**4) Number of read requests performed on the table
5) Number of write requests performed on the table**

There are DB* tables that contain such kind of info. Specifically I am referring to DB6PMHST and DB6HISTBS. When I try to view them via SE11 or SE16, system reports that these tables do not hold any records. I tried all three development, testing and production landscapes.
Please may you provide a guidance on what I am doing wrong? Maybe there are some other system tables that would contain the necessary info?
P.S. I tried to debug ST04 transaction in order to see the tables from which the report selects data, but wasn't able to find those lines of the source code.

I would deeply appreciate your kind assistance.

P.S.S. Checked the table MSSDBSTATT - it is empty as well (our enterprise uses MS SQL Database)

Comment: The DB*-tables seem to be specific to IBM DB2 databases. They are empty on our system with an oracle database. You may need to find the tables according to the database you're using.

Comment: Sir, I am grateful for your insight. May you please advice where I can find more info about the specific database systems and their corresponding "DB*" tables (particularly MSSQL)?

Comment: Number of reads since when?

Comment: In a specified period of time, which will be specified by the user on the selection screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of reads and writes on a table is a subject specific to the type of database (**MSSQL**) -> please tag your question accordingly.

If you get an answer by an MSSQL expert, which says that the data is stored in some MSSQL tables, then you cannot query those tables using "Open SQL" but you may query them using "native SQL" (i.e. `EXEC SQL` or ADBC for instance).

Answer (score 3):

Go to SE38 and run this report RSTABLESIZE, enter table ID and see the magic.

[image: RSTABLESIZE]

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful